# ReCaptcha in Classic ASP - Form not responding to it

Tags: asp-classic, recaptcha

**Here is the scenario:**

1. I have a form on a Classic ASP page.
2. I have set up the public and private key within the ASP code and have placed this in the `<head>`.
3. I have inserted the recaptcha HTML skeleton within my `<form>` tags---
   here my form breaks

**Occurrence:**

The captcha displays, but my form is not responding to it.
My form does not submit once I insert the captcha.
The captcha doesn't even respond if it is inputted correctly or not.

What am I doing wrong? Am I suppose to edit something in the skeleton?
What does the form action do in this code? Is it needed?

**The skeleton is the Google code below:**

```
<% if server_response <> "" or newCaptcha then %>

<% if newCaptcha = False then %>
  Wrong!
<% end if %>

<!-- Generating the form -->
<form action="recaptcha.asp" method="post">
  <%=recaptcha_challenge_writer()%>
</form>

<% else %>
  Correct!
<%end if%>
```

I appreciate any help you may have to offer, thank you.

Comment: By removing the form action displayed here and inheriting the form action I have in my original form, the recaptcha is recognized. However, it passes anything typed in the input. I'm closer but the captcha check is not working now.

Comment: can you post more of your page?  Like where is newCaptcha set?

Comment: The next step for recaptcha is this: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html  But this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I switched to another captcha, and my code is stuck here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?811951-Classic-ASP-Captcha-Missing-Check-Concept

Comment: have you written out your response?  Are you sure the captcha is getting the right values.

Comment: Hi Robert. When the captcha is singled out and alone, I can get it to work great. However, once I start adding other fields elements (like name, email, etc), the form breaks. See the post below regarding the tipstricks.org approach and the issue I am discussing with Salt. This is where I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 1):

take a look http://www.tipstricks.org

it's an easy and useful captcha solution. Create and download customized captcha code with an usage sample.

Comment: Thanks Salt. I was recommended this and switched over, but I'm still missing a big yet probably simple concept. I can get the captcha to work fine; but once I put in the form action, any captcha input goes. It's driving me crazy because I am misunderstanding a concept that should be quite simple. I have my code outlined here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?811951-Classic-ASP-Captcha-Missing-Check-Concept  If you could review it, I would so appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: hi.. remove action="thankyou.asp"  from form tag.  and add  response.redirect("thankyou.asp") after "if StrComp(TestValue, Trim(Session("ASPCAPTCHA")), 1) = 0 then"  line.. try again.

Comment: Thanks Salt. I have tried this, and the captcha works...however, the data is not being sent in the e-mail. The field values are empty. This method treats the captcha like it's own form action, and the rest of the form fields (like name, email, etc) are overlooked.

Comment: I got the form to transfer the data, and the captcha works. However, now the thankyou.asp page is stuck in an iframe-like thing on the page when the user hits submit. It's not opening the thankyou.asp page as a new independent window, but rather opening it within the original form page. I have the full conversation and code on this here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?811951-Classic-ASP-Captcha-Missing-Check-Concept&p=5022043#post5022043  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sooo close yet so stuck. lol